# How can I get data between due date in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have a database with a lot of tasks, every task has a project, so when i want to take a tasks from one project I can do just this:

```
ProjectHasTask::all(array('conditions' => array('status = ? AND project_id = ? ', 'done', $project_id)));
```

In the datebase the table with *tasks* I have a VARCHAR column with "due_date" name, I want to get only the tasks that are made between two dates (from_date and to_date)

Anyone can suggest me how I can do it correctly? I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
$tasks_done = ProjectHasTask::all(array('conditions' => array('status = ? AND project_id = ? AND due_date <= ? AND due_date >= ?', 'done', $project_id, $from_date->getTimestamp(), $to_date->getTimestamp())));
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the due_date column contains timestamp values. Otherwise this query is meaningless.

I believe all you need is a couple sets of well places parentheses.

```
$tasks_done = ProjectHasTask::all(array('conditions' => 
    array('(status = ? AND project_id = ?) AND (due_date <= ? AND due_date >= ?)', 
    'done', $project_id, $from_date->getTimestamp(), $to_date->getTimestamp())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM table_name 
        WHERE status = '$status' 
        AND project_id = $pid 
        AND (due_date BETWEEN '$due_date' AND '$due_date_2')
    ")
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

> **Note : ** This is not `due_date <= ? AND due_date >= ?'` good argument at all. Use `BETWEEN` or use `==` to get exact date